# Powershell get particular MAC address in string format

Tags: powershell

I have an issue with my code - I can grab particular MACadress and convert it into string. Problem, is that in my method, it takes some illegal characters:

```
$CurrMac = get-netadapter | Where {$_.name -Match "Ethernet 2"}
$CurrMacAddr = $CurrMac.MacAddress
out-string -inputobject $CurrMacAddr -outvariable CurrMac2
$CurrMac2 = $CurrMac2.Substring(0,$CurrMac2.Length-1)
```

So, my question - is there any other way to extract mac address for adapter with name "Ethernet 2" in string without special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `Out-String` - the `MacAddress` property is *already a string*.

If you want to replace the `-` characters, you could use either `String.Replace()`:

```
$CurrMacAddr = $CurrMac.MacAddress.Replace('-','')
```

or the `-replace` operator:

```
$CurrMacAddr = $CurrMac.MacAddress -replace '-'
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement the existing, helpful answers with a PowerShell-idiomatic PSv4+ solution based on the `.Where()` array method, which performs better than use of the `Where-Object` cmdlet:

```
PS> (Get-NetAdapter).Where({ $_.Name -match 'Ethernet 2'}).MacAddress -replace '-'
00B0362FF73A  # e.g.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$adapter = Get-NetAdapter | Where {$_.Name -Match "Ethernet 2"}
$result = $adapter.MacAddress.Replace("-", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way

- Pass the Name directly to `Get-NetAdapter`
- split the `MacAddress` at the '-'
- join the resulting array

---

```
(Get-NetAdapter 'Ethernet 2').MacAddress -split '-' -join ''
```